# Чем является минимальный примитив синхронизации в С/C++?

Tags: c++, синхронизация

Критические секции Windows, std::mutex, std::atomic... Но на чём-то ведь это всё построено, на какой-то базовой атомарной инструкции? Что это может быть? Как реализован тот же atomic?

Можно ли сделать свою синхронизацию, так сказать, без include-ов?

Comment: Есть определенные ассемблерные коды, в часности `lock` префикс, которые обеспечивают правильное поведение операции присваивания.

Answer (score 1):

в конечном итоге все приходит к CompareExchange

Answer (score 0):

[futex](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81) процессорные локи.

> Сходным образом оптимизированы объекты CRITICAL_SECTION в Win32 API, а также FAST_MUTEX в [ядре Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/cc164040(en-us).aspx)

можно написать свою синхронизацию используя futex